# Is it possible to subdivide a regular polygon of side-length $n$ into equilateral polygons of side-length $1$?

Tags: geometry

Suppose I have a regular polygon whose sides each measure $n$. I want to cut it up into smaller equilateral (but not necessarily regular) polygons whose sides each measure $1$.

Is this possible? If yes, what's a simple (easy to implement) algorithm that can generate the subdivision?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: There seems to be a way to do it for $n$ even: First dissect into rhombi, as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodecagon#Dissection), then subdivide those rhombi into $n$ by $n$ grids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this strategy for regular polygons with an internal angle greater than $120$ (that is, with $7$ or more sides): use $n$ equilateral triangles of side length $1$ to cover each side of the polygon, so that the uncovered region also forms an equilateral polygon of side length $1$.

Here's an example for a regular heptagon:

[image]

The importance of the internal angle greater than $120$ is, of course, so that the equilateral triangles don't overlap at the corner.

If your regular polygon have $3$, $4$ or $6$ sides, the situation is easy to handle. If it have $5$ sides, a similar strategy will work, so the answer to your question is: yes, it's always possible.

Comment: Why exclude the regular hexagon?

Comment: Your main strategy works fine for the regular hexagon. There's no reason to insist that the angle is *strictly greater* than $120^\circ$, only that it be *at least* $120^\circ$.